# How to set one page PageSetup.PageSize in Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I tried this :

```
range= wDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
object Type = Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak;
range.InsertBreak(ref Type);
range.PageSetup.PaperSize = Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaperCSheet;
```

but it set all pages to `wdPaperCSheet`.

How can I set one page to wdPaperCSheet ?

Comment: I know that maybe the scope problem,and I have tried paragraph,document.It can not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried much time.and last I found the solution.

```
range= wDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
object Type = Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage;
range.InsertBreak(ref Type);
range.PageSetup.PaperSize = Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaperCSheet;
```

this code will set pages after the the range to wdPaperCSheet.and we can do this again to make pages to be normal.so at last we can make one page to wdPaperCSheet.
but i could't know why wdPageBreak  and wdSectionBreakNextPage take this different.Could someone explain it.

Comment: It is my thinking.wdBrakPage it insert a page,but for the document it means just one page,so make all pages to that. wdSectionBreakNextPage it means another page not for one page.I am right, aren't I